# load json into d3.js for use in Radial Dendrogram

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

so javascript newbie here, been banging my head on how to get JSON [source json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/liskl/2e492744e00b169e17317e5937f1c4e5/raw/018e5b3a44a5884ea4826f401af652a1b4c512fa/sample_idrac_json_export.json)
loaded into d3.js Radial Dendrogram graph.
located here: [d3.js Radial Dendrogram graph example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4739610f6d96aaad2fb1e78a72b385ab)

the current plan is to import JSON into python
or maybe convert the json into a 2 column (id,value) csv using python.

but i would love to understand the how this can be accomplished as i've been banging my head on javascript and d3.js for almost 2 days now.

Basically i'm trying to load the data into d3.js
to allow the visualization of the following

with the root being system

**EDIT:** to show the hopeful tendril flow

```
system --> model_type --> system_revision --> firmware_version --> firmware_build, system_name
```

to follow the example csv given in the link above.

```
id,value
systems,
systems_PowerEdge R720xd,
systems_PowerEdge R720xd_I,
systems_PowerEdge R720xd_I_1.50.50,
systems_PowerEdge R720xd_I_1.50.50_34,ldc0000
```

is the kind of output i would love to get.

Comment: Given your JSON, what would the dendrogram look like?

Comment: Editted the original post to better explain the ask.

Comment: I wouldn't convert my `JSON` to `csv` just to convert back to `JSON`.  The real question you should be asking is how to reformat my `JSON` to the hierarchical structure `d3` needs.  Looking at the example you link to, the structure is in the `root` object, `{id: "flare", children: [ {id: "one", children: [...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just coming back to this question from yesterday.  As I said in my comment, you need to convert your JSON structure to the parent/child hierarchy required by [d3.hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy).  Unfortunately, your source data is not really hierarchical at all, so the only way I see to do this is in a very manual manner:

```
var root = {
    id: "system",
    children: []
  };
  data.systems.forEach(function(d,i){
    var key = Object.keys(d)[0],
        sysInfo = d[key].sysInfo;
    root.children.push({
      id: sysInfo.system_model,
      children: [{
        id: sysInfo.system_revision,
        children: [{
          id: sysInfo.firmware_version,
          children: [{
            id: sysInfo.firmware_build
          }, {
            id: key
          }]
        }]
      }]
    });
  });

  root = d3.hierarchy(root);
```

After that the dendrogram code remains unchanged except for fixing the text labels:

```
.text(function(d) { console.log(d); return d.data.id });
```

---

Full running [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCVqfbxyg0384kjYtFrk?p=preview).